# Check if the current user has liked the posts of a firebase list

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm struggling with this logic and can't find where I'm mistaken. I'm using AngularFire, Ionic 3 and Firebase.

I have a news feed. It is populated by posts from this firebase call:

`this.postlist = this.db.list('/posts/').map( (arr) => { return arr.reverse();});`

In my view, an `*ngFor` loops through the list of posts to display them.

**Now for where I'm stuck.**

I want to display a full red heart on the post if the current user has liked it already. I want it to be grey and outlined if not.

In my view, I have this:

```
<button ion-button icon-start (click)="likePost(post)" *ngIf="!likedPost(post)">
    <ion-icon name="md-heart-outline"></ion-icon> {{post.likes}}
</button>

<button ion-button icon-start (click)="likePost(post)" *ngIf="likedPost(post)">
    <ion-icon name="md-heart" color="redtext"></ion-icon> {{post.likes}}
</button>
```

My `likedPost()` function looks like that:

```
likedPost(post){

  //Init my own id
  let myId = this.userid;

  //Fetch the likes for this post in the firebase db
  let postLikersList = firebase.database().ref(`/likes/${post.$key}`); 

  //Check in postCheck if the list of likes for this post has one that is mine
  postLikersList.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
    var postCheck = snapshot.hasChild(`${myId}`);

      if (!postCheck) {

        //Outlined button
        return false;

      } else {

        //Full red button
        return true;

      }
    });
}
```

It seems to work when I log the results in the console, but the button doesn't change at all.

Hope you can help me and it can help other people with the same problem.
Have a good day!

Comment: You need to show the `*ngFor` also on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to maintain array object like this `post.islikedPost` and changed its value according to your use case.Then use it as shown below.

*.html*

```
<button ion-button icon-start (click)="likedPost(post)" *ngIf="!post.islikedPost">
    <ion-icon name="md-heart-outline"></ion-icon> {{post.likes}}
</button>

<button ion-button icon-start (click)="likedPost(post)" *ngIf="post.islikedPost">
    <ion-icon name="md-heart" color="redtext"></ion-icon> {{post.likes}}
</button>
```

Another variation of this is where you don't need 2 buttons at all.You can do it like this.

```
<button ion-button icon-start (click)="likedPost(post)">
 <ion-icon name="md-heart-outline" *ngIf="!post.islikedPost"></ion-icon> {{post.likes}}
 <ion-icon name="md-heart" color="redtext" *ngIf="post.islikedPost"></ion-icon> {{post.likes}}
</button>
```

Comment: I don't get how that works. I tried it but I have multiple posts in the feed, so how can I use only one public member to define if some of the posts have been liked?

Comment: OK then maintain that variable inside the `post`.

Comment: And how can I check the value of post.islikedPost as post is just an iteration of a firebase list which doesn't include the islikedPost variable?

`<ion-item *ngFor="let post of postlist | async" class="postItem">`

Comment: Okay, I added a call `{{setLiked(post)}}` to the loop so I can set the post.islikedPost variable. Thanks a lot for your help!